# Blender 2.79 + 2.80 internationalization translations german

Tags: customization

Where can I get the source code of Blender 2.8 velvet blender.pot for 2.8?

git.blender nothing 2.8

wiki.blender nothing 2.8

Please make a translate plugin in the forum here.

https://github.com/BigManzai/blender_german

Comment: This is not the place to post translations, I suggest you contact the developers at [the corresponding mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/)

Comment: Translation contributions should be made against blenders [translation repo](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BT/) and submitted to [dev.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/differential/diff/create/) where there is a [translations project](https://developer.blender.org/tag/translations/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about program translation and should be reported to the developers.

Comment: I just wanted to show that translation is something that others can do.
If you search Google for german translation you will only find stackexchange.com. 

Ich wollte nur zeigen das etwas an der Translation getan wird und andere dies Testen können.
Wenn man in Google nach German Translation sucht findet man nur stackexchange.com.

Comment: The rules of this site state posts should be in English language only